# Gradle | publishToMavenLocal | How to exclude Release related tasks

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, maven-publish

I have a multi-module Android project and I'm able to publish all modules to Nexus.

I noticed after running `publishToMavenLocal` it runs:

- preReleaseBuild
- compileReleaseAidl
- compileReleaseRenderscript
- more...

and each of them per module so I have `:module1:compileReleaseRenderscript` and `:module2:compileReleaseRenderscript`

For doing quick tests, I would like to exclude Release (or Debug) tasks so the build is faster.

How could I exclude running Release related tasks from `publishToMavenLocal` for ALL modules?